# What is a "Froyo"?

Tags: android-versions

The older Android versions are called "cupcake" and "eclair". Where does 2.2 get it's name from?

Comment: It's actually Froyo, not FroYo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's short for *Fro* zen *Yo* ghurt. I have no idea who came up with the idea to name it after frozen yoghurt though.

Comment: Hehe. Cool. ...

Comment: They go alphabetically, Donut, Elcair, Froyo, Gingerbread, Honeycomb...  I guess they could have also gone with Frappe.

Comment: @Matt - Don't forget Cupcake. They go from Cupcake to Zatar.

Comment: http://cache.gizmodo.com/assets/images/4/2009/05/cupacake_01.jpg

Comment: Whoops, how could I forget Cupcake!?  What do you think they'll do for X?

Comment: @Matt - Xiaodianxin.

Answer (score 2):

They'd all be desserts or sugary goods.

After Gingerbread (2.3) and Honeycomb (3.x) it's rumoured to be Ice Cream - see the pattern?